# javascript hex codes with TCP/IP communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I’m using a node module ‘net’ to create a client application that sends data through a TCP socket. The server-side application accepts this message if it starts and ends with a correct hex code, just for example the data packet would start with a hex “0F” and ends with a hex “0F1C”. How would I create these hex codes with javascript ? I found this code to convert a UTF-8 string into a hex code, not sure if this is what I need as I don’t have much experience with TCP/IP socket connections. Heres some javascript I've used to convert a utf-8 to a hex code. But I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for? Does anyone have experience with TCP/IP transfers and/or javascript hex codes?.

```
function toHex(str,hex){
  try{
    hex = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))
    .split('').map(function(v){
      return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    }).join('')
  }
  catch(e){
    hex = str
    console.log('invalid text input: ' + str)
  }
  return hex
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you do not need to convert your data string into hex values, in order to send it over TCP. Every string in node.js is converted to bytes when sent over the network.

Normally, you'd send over a string like so:

```
var data = "ABC";
socket.write(data); // will send bytes 65 66 67, or in hex: 44 45 46
```

Node.JS also allows you to pass `Buffer` objects to functions like `.write()`.
So, probably the easiest way to achieve what you wish, is to create an appropriate buffer to hold your data.

```
var data = "ABC";
var prefix = 0x0F; // JavaScript allows hex numbers.
var suffix = 0x0FC1;
var dataSize = Buffer.byteLength(data);
// compute the required buffer length
var bufferSize = 1 + dataSize + 2;
var buffer = new Buffer(bufferSize);

// store first byte on index 0;
buffer.writeUInt8(prefix, 0);

// store string starting at index 1;
buffer.write(data, 1, dataSize);

// stores last two bytes, in big endian format for TCP/IP.
buffer.writeUInt16BE(suffix, bufferSize - 2);

socket.write(buffer);
```

**Explanation:**

The `prefix` hex value `0F` requires 1 byte of space. The `suffix` hex value `0FC1` actually requires two bytes (a 16-bit integer).

When computing the number of required bytes for a string *(JavaScript strings are UTF-16 encoded!)*, `str.length` is not accurate most of the times, especially when your string has non-ASCII characters in it. For this, the proper way of getting the byte size of a string is to use `Buffer.byteLength()`.

`Buffers` in node.js have static allocations, meaning you can't resize them after you created them. Hence, you'll need to compute the size of the buffer *-in bytes-* before creating it. Looking at our data, that is `1` (for our prefix) + `Buffer.byteLength(data)` (for our data) + `2` (for our suffix).

After that *-imagine buffers as arrays of bytes (8-bit values)-*, we'll populate the buffer, like so:

1. write the first byte (the `prefix`) using `writeUInt8(byte, offset)` with offset `0` in our buffer.
2. write the data string, using `.write(string[, offset[, length]][, encoding])`, starting at offset `1` in our buffer, and length `dataSize`.
3. write the last two bytes, using `.writeUInt16BE(value, offset)` with offset `bufferSize - 2`. We're using `writeUInt16BE` to write the 16-bit value in **big-endian** encoding, which is what you'd need for TCP/IP.

Once we've filled our buffer with the correct data, we can send it over the network, using `socket.write(buffer)`;

**Additional tip:**

If you really want to convert a large string to bytes, (e.g. to later print as hex), then `Buffer` is also great:

```
var buf = Buffer.from('a very large string');
// now you have a byte represetantion of the string.
```

Since bytes are all 0-255 decimal values, you can easily print them as hex values in console, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
  const byte = buf[i];
  const hexChar = byte.toString(16); // convert the decimal `byte` to hex string;
  // do something with hexChar, e.g. console.log(hexChar);
}
```

Comment: @MihaiPorta this is great explanation. It clears a lot up for me. However, I still can't understand how to generate the prefix and suffix. If I console.log(prefix) it returns 15? you've mentioned javascript allows hex numbers, but how does var = 0x0F; result in 15 when console.logged ?

Comment: With javascript hex number do you just start the variable with '0x' and than whatever you like? when you console log it out the 0 doesn't show, is it really there?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript syntax allows you to use hex values, by prepending it with `0x`. All hex values are actually numbers (decimals in base 16). `0x0F === 15`. They're the same thing, so `console.log` will always output the decimal (base 10) representation.

Comment: Also, `0x0F` is the same as `0xF`, just as `15` in base 10 is the same with `015`. When using hex values, you usually include the leading `0` to better show byte alignment, since every two pair in hex is one byte long. E.g. `0x0c01` is the same with `0xc01` meaning two bytes `0c` and `01`

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been extremely helpful and this  is a great explanation of javascript hex codes in a TCP/IP environment.